# batch file execution failing with PostBuildScript plugin of jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to execute a batch file to copy my files to another server under the 'execute batch or shell script' option of PostBuildScript plugin of jenkins.
Below are the commands in my .bat file.

```
net use \\192.168.20.48 /user:admin password
xcopy "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Deployment code Test" "\\DeployServer\Workspace\Builds" /S/E/H/D/Y/V/C/I/K/R/X
```

When the .bat file is run from a command prompt it runs as expected and completing its actions. My problem is that when I run it through Jenkins it gives following error messages:

System error 1312 has occurred.
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
Invalid drive specification
0 File(s) copied

any work around for this..?

Answer (score 2):

The "net use" command is not available when running a LocalSystem account.  Change the account that's running Jenkins, or use the [Publish Over CIFS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin).

Comment: How to change the account that running Jenkins? I am working with Administrator account and thus I am confused about this bug..

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager -> Services Tab -> Click Services button -> Select Jenkins Services -> Right click and go to Properties -> select Log On tab -> Select 'This Account' as the log on option -> Enter Administrator credentials -> Apply, Save and Restart the Service solved the issue.